# Starting VB Script from Powershell script - works from PS environment, but not scheduled task

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm trying to ensure a process is running on my machine, so I decided to setup a scheduled task to check & restart it hourly if no longer running.  The challenge is it's a Java process started via a vb script (yuk!).  The biggest original hurdle was starting it in the correct working directory so Java was happy, but I ironed that out.

I figured out how to track the process and restart if needed.  This ps1 script works perfectly if I run it directly from within the powershell environment.

LNGS_restart.ps1 -->

```
$cmdArgs='/c cscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\LNGoogleCalSync\lngsync.vbs"';
$workingDirectory="C:\Program Files (x86)\LNGoogleCalSync\";

#Do select-string twice so we exclude the commandlet that actually finds the pattern (since that shouldn't count as a hit!)
if( -Not (WmiObject Win32_Process | select commandline | Select-String -pattern 'lngs' | Select-String -pattern pattern -notmatch -quiet))
{start -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList $cmdArgs -NoNewWindow -WorkingDirectory $workingDirectory }
```

Running the above from within powershell environment works great.  Running it from command prompt or scheduled task doesn't work (won't start the process, it just does nothing and returns).

```
c:\jobs>powershell c:\jobs\LNGS_restart.ps1
```

What is going on?  I'm not sure why it won't work outside powershell environment and how to fix it so that I can then schedule it via task scheduler

> Program/Script:  powershell.exe
>
> Arguments: -command "c:\jobs\LNGS_restart.ps1"

Any help?

Comment: First thing I'd check is the permissions of the process run from DOS / task scheduler. Start dos prompt as admin and work from there?

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap this in PowerShell? Doing this in batch or extending the VBScript with the check would probably be a lot simpler.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - 1) I tried from dos, but it wasn't very reliable for some reason it worked most times, but sometimes gave unpredictable results, and 2) I wanted to work on my PowerShell scripting skills and thought it *should* be doable in PS, but it's not cooperating....

Comment: @chappoo - I was running from "normal" prompt.  For kicks I just tried it from an "administrator command prompt" and regular, and both prompts behave the same as the scheduled taks (ie do not work).  FYI - the scheduled task is setup with my User/Pass credentials stored in the job.

Comment: There is no reason why `cscript "C:\...\lngsync.vbs"` would work reliably from a PowerShell prompt, but not from a normal command prompt (which hasn't anything to do with DOS at all). Please show what you tried in a command prompt. It might be helpful if you showed the VBScript code as well (make sure to obfuscate credentials and such).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - the LNGS.vbs can be obtained from here:

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - the LNGS.vbs can be obtained from here: [package download site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lngooglecalsync/?source=dlp) or directly via this link: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/88L2WX3h) and as I showed above how I run it in the command prompt by kicking of the ps1 script embedded in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this batch script as a scheduled task:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "programdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\LNGoogleCalSync"
set "script=%programdir%\lngsync.vbs"

pushd "%programdir%"

wmic process get commandline | findstr /r [l]ngs >nul || cscript "%script%"

popd
```

If that doesn't work: try replacing all `MsgBox` statements in the VBScript with `WScript.Echo`.

Comment: how do I specify a working directory with cscript?  The above example seems to work for detection, but when invoking cscript to start the vbs file, it doesn't work for my example because the script complains about a whole bunch of crap unless you specify the working dir as "C:\Program Files (x86)\LNGoogleCalSync" when you fire it off from a bat file or task.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Invoke-Item:

```
Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\LNGoogleCalSync\lngsync.vbs"
```

This also resolve the current directory problem.